# Specifying quantity in django models OneToMany

Tags: python, django

I've been searching across the interwebs and can't seem to find a way to specify a quantity with django models ForeignKey field. For example, I want to create an apartment model and only want 4 tenant models to be associated with the apartment model.

class apartmen(...):

```
...
```

class tenant(...):

```
tenants = ForeingKey(apartment, limit_choices_to ={(Only allow 4 per apartment model)}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `limit_choices` limits the values, not the number of items. You will need to write a validator or a signal handler validating the number.

Comment: Awesome, I wasn't aware of those other options. Was stuck trying to use ForeignKey to limit the number of items.

Comment: just check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20203806/limit-maximum-choices-of-manytomanyfield