# Better way to add multiple field to this model?

Tags: django, django-models

In my Django project I have a model for a drinks recipe that allows up to 10 ingredients plus their amount.
I am wondering if it's possible to make this in a more DRY way than I do now?
This is the model I am using currently:

```
class Recipe(models.Model):
    ingr_name1 = models.CharField(max_length=250, verbose_name='Ingredient')
    ingr_amount1 = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=1, verbose_name='Amount')
    ingr_name2 = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Ingredient')
    ingr_amount2 = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=1,blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Amount')
    ingr_name3 = models.CharField(max_length=250,blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Ingredient')
    ingr_amount3 = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=1,blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Amount')
    ingr_name4 = models.CharField(max_length=250,blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Ingredient')
    ingr_amount4 = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=1,blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Amount')
    ingr_name5 = models.CharField(max_length=250,blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Ingredient')
    ingr_amount5 = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=1,blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Amount')
    ingr_name6 = models.CharField(max_length=250,blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Ingredient')
    ingr_amount6 = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=1,blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Amount')
    ingr_name7 = models.CharField(max_length=250,blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Ingredient')
    ingr_amount7 = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=1,blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Amount')
    ingr_name8 = models.CharField(max_length=250,blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Ingredient')
    ingr_amount8 = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=1,blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Amount')
    ingr_name9 = models.CharField(max_length=250,blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Ingredient')
    ingr_amount9 = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=1,blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Amount')
    ingr_name10 = models.CharField(max_length=250,blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Ingredient')
    ingr_amount10 = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=1,blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Amount')
    drink_name = models.CharField(max_length=250,blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Drink name')
    drink_story = models.TextField()
    drink_picture = ResizedImageField(upload_to='drinks/', null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.drink_name
```

Comment: You can create a table which contain all the information about ingredient & amout eg. `Ingredient` -> `name`, `amount` & then link then with your drink table.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to make Ingredient its own model and add is as a many to many field in the recipe model. Then based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20230270/9638991) you can limit the number of ingredients to 10 by adding a `ingredients_changed()` function to the Recipe model.

Untested code below:

```
class Ingredient(model.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    amount = models.CharField()

class Recipe(models.Model):
    ingredients = models.ManyToManyField(Ingredient)

    def ingredients_changed(recipe, **kwargs):
        if kwargs['instance'].ingredients.count() > 10:
            raise ValidationError("You can't assign more than 10 ingredients")
```

Comment: This looks like it makes sense. How do I work my form and view with these? I've never used ManyToMany fields before.

Comment: That’s a separate question and depends entirely on what you’re doing. I’d recommend reading the docs on Many to Many Relationships (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/ ) and the ManyToManyField (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField) to get started

Answer (score -1):

You could think of an alternative model field such as a JSONField or a TextField.
JSONFields are a good one, if you:

1. Don't know how many ingr_amounts& ingr_names are used
2. If you want to handle them together. Within you're current model you would have to do a clean based on each self.ingr, with a jsonfield you could do it with one self.my_json_field.

Anyways there also disadvantages and you, especially when querying and updating jsonfields it can get trickier. So before you go ahead and use it please infrom here f.ex. [JSONField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/fields/#jsonfield), [json query](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/queries/#querying-jsonfield)

*You could also if it fits you're needs create a new Model with both fields and link it to the other model via a ForeignKey

Comment: The canonical way of doing that is to use a related model, a JSONField could be use but that's really an anti-pattern.